# Find the most frequest value in a list explanation

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is more of a question for explanation rather than answer. I tried to google search but I'm having a hard time understanding this piece of code.

Find The Most Frequent Value In A List.

```
test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4] 
print(max(set(test), key = test.count))
```

How does the above code works?
max() is to find the largest value which I guess in this case comparing `set(test)` vs `test.count`?

set(test) is to create a set from the array

I'm not sure how to read `key = test.count` looking at google search .count() is for array is supposed to find the number of occurent like `test.count(2)`, it should return 3 occurences

if people can point me to the right documentation that would also be great.

Comment: The [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) builtin, takes the `key` argument `test.count` on which to sort the input list and determine the max. Here `test.count` takes as input the set of numbers, computes the count of each number, and returns the number with max count `4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set(test)` creates a set of unique values, then `max` find maximum from these values based on `test.count` which returns number of occurrences in list `test`.

Here are some examples using `max` with `key`

```py
l = [-2, -1, 0, 1]
print(max(l, key=lambda x: x**2))
# prints -2

l = [[0], [0,1,2], [0,1]]
print(max(l, key=len))
# prints [0,1,2]

l = [[0], [0,1,2], [0,4]]
print(max(l, key=max))
# prints [0,4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, **test.count** will give you the number of occurrences for every list element and 
   **max** will return mostly occurred number.

Answer (score 1):

test is a list, and in Python, there is a [count](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method associated with `lists` - it returns the number of times an item appears in the list.

So, in the `test` list, 1 appears twice, 2 appears three times, 3 appears twice, and 4 appears four times.

The built in function `max` searches for the maximum item, and the maximum item is based on the `key` criteria. In written words, we could interprete it as : `Return the item in the list with the highest frequency`. Since the number 4 has the highest frequency(it appears four times), the code returns 4.

Let's change the contents of test and see if our explanation holds :

```
test = [1,5, 2, 5,3, 4,5, 2, 2,5, 3, 1,5, 4, 4,5, 4,]
```

For this new data, the number with the highest frequency is 5 ( it appears six times in the test list). Our code should return 5.

```
print(max((test), key = test.count))

5
```

On a side note, I do not think that there is a need to wrap `test` in `set`, as `max` will just return one number that matches the criteria.